# How do I install an air conditioner on a horizontal sliding double window that has a 51/2 inch gap between the 2 windows?

Tags: air-conditioning, installation

I have a double horizontally sliding window (like a lot of homes in Canada). The windows are about 51/2 inches apart. I want to install a regular 10,000 BTU air conditioner in the window but I don't know how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Google installing window a/c in horizontal sliding window and look at videos. E.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGUH4PguUQM

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 5.5in (normally written 5 1/2"). That's too narrow for any window unit. You should get a portable in-room air conditioner, where the machinery sits inside your home and you just have exhaust hoses that need to vent to outside through your window.

[image: Portable AC with horizontal sliding window installation]

Comment: This will tend to draw warm air into your house, unless you also run a pipe for the condenser inlet.